# How to make a table with multiple columns in one row

Tags: tables, errors

My question is how to make all given columns in one row instead of two rows shown in the following table. Thanks.

[image]

```
\begin{table*}[h!]
% \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\scalebox{0.7}{
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
            \toprule
            {} &   K-means &        NMF &              LSNMF &             nsNMF &                PMF &               SNMF &   ANMF &          Ours \\
            \midrule
            \textit{Heart}  & 0.030     & 0.101 $\pm$ 0.047 &  0.131 $\pm$ 0.004 & \textbf{0.236 $\pm$ 0.124} &  0.213 $\pm$ 0.106 &  0.188 $\pm$ 0.071 & 00 &0.201 $\pm$ 0.059 \\
            \textit{Ionosphere} & 0.015 & 0.060 $\pm$ 0.007 &  0.066 $\pm$ 0.008 &  0.067 $\pm$ 0.015 &  0.071 $\pm$ 0.008 &  0.077 $\pm$ 0.025 & 00 & \textbf{0.479 $\pm$ 0.014} \\
            \textit{Wine}  & 0.371 & 0.743 $\pm$ 0.035 &    0.75 $\pm$ 0.018 &  0.738 $\pm$ 0.033 &  0.751 $\pm$ 0.013 &   0.755 $\pm$ 0.012 & 00 &  \textbf{0.857 $\pm$ 0.024} \\
\end{tabular}
}

\end{table*}
```

Comment: `\begin{table*}[h!]`  Please always show a complete small test document not a fragment. `table*` makes a table spanning both columns of a two column document and does not have an `h` option.

Comment: Never ignore errors, you get the error `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` because you have not declared enough columns. use `{ccccccccc}` (also avoid using scalebox on tables.

Comment: ...for simplicity, rather use something like `{ *{9}{c} }` since it's clearer there are 9 columns.